# Fortran program to read an input file and determine the min and max values and what line they are in the file

Tags: fortran

I need help writing a program to read in a file with an unknown amount of lines of numbers and to determine the minimum and maximum values of that file. The input file is formatted as one value per line. I’m not sure how to locate and store the maximum and minimum values as well as what line they’re on without intrinsic functions. (Instructed not to use intrinsic functions). Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Educational answer incoming (not exact code):

```
   open(unit=122,file="path_to_file_with_extension"))
    do
     read(122,*) variab
    enddo
```

This bit of code will read a file line by line **for ever** (therefore, giving an error once it reaches the end of the file) and assigning what it reads to the variable *variab*. If you want to stop when it reaches the last line of the file then you need to add a parameter in the read command, specifically the iostat parameter, which takes various values depending on the state of the read command ([read here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-read-statement)). That means, that by checking the value of iostat you can check whether you reached the end of the file or not. When you did, you can exit the do loop easily with an [exit](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/561/Syllabus/5-Fortran/do.html) statement.

As for the min/max part.Think about what minimum and maximum means and how yourself would do the check. If it were me, and I wanted to find what the maximum number in file is, I would probably do something like that, in my head:

- "The maximum number of the file is the first one (e.g 5) (why not, right?) and I write in a little notepad max:5, position:1"
- "Is the second number (e.g 2) bigger than the current maximum (i.e first one)?"
- "In this case, it's not, so I don't write down anything and continue"
- "is the third number (e.g 16) bigger than the current maximum (i.e the first one)?"
- "In my case it is, so I write in my notepad, max:16, position:3"

If you continue like that you would find the maximum of the file and where it is.

The process for the minimum value would be exactly the same, but checking for the smaller number, not the greater.

I could give out the whole code but seeing how easy it is, it tells me that you are just learning programming and I think it would be better to find out by yourself and fill in the gaps of my answer